# Change column-width and count

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns, making for a 940px wide container.
Is possible in one layout to use a different type of column layout?

I looked tool http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

I want that 1 block have 7 columns -system(span1-span7 max),2 block have 12 columns(span1-span12 max) -system .
It's real?

Comment: you need to have 31 column :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have 31 column in customize bootstrap. set `@gridColumns` to 31 and you can edit `@gridColumnWidth` and other fields as you like. look at this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">span12</div>
  <div class="span7">span7</div>
  <div class="span12">span12</div>
</div>
```